# How many ways are there to seat six people around a circular table

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

> How many ways are there to seat six people around a circular table
> where two seatings are considered the same when everyone has the same
> two neighbors without regard to whether they are right or left
> neighbors?

I know we have to apply division rule. I also know by rotating at six position we overcount by factor of 6 but that gives me answer of 120, while the correct answer is 60.

How to solve this?

Comment: $6$ people sit on a circular table in $(6-1)! = 120$ ways

Comment: Now if left or right neighbours do not matter, that is $1/2$.

Comment: Said differently:  For each of your solutions, *flip* one clockwise-to-counterclockwise.  They're equivalent.  Hence divide by $2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the guests can sit around the table in $6! = 720$ ways. Since two seatings are considered equal if they all have the same neighbor, the location of the first person, does not matter. Hence, a division by $6$. Also, since the left/right orientation is not an issue, we can 'flip' (place the first person at a seat, and instead of adding persons to the right, do it to the left) the seating and thus divide by $2$. This gives $60$ seatings in total.